# Swift code crashing and not working

Tags: swift, function, sprite-kit

After adding code into my `update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval)` function, my app's code continues to crash. Is there a better way to express my code so it doesn't crash?

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

var startScreen = SKSpriteNode()
var Ball = SKSpriteNode()
var playerPaddle = SKSpriteNode()
var computerPaddle = SKSpriteNode()
var playerScore = SKLabelNode()
var comScore = SKLabelNode()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

    startScreen = childNode(withName: "startScreen") as! SKSpriteNode
    Ball = childNode(withName: "Ball") as! SKSpriteNode
    playerPaddle = childNode(withName: "playerPaddle") as! SKSpriteNode
    computerPaddle = childNode(withName: "computerPaddle") as! SKSpriteNode
    playerScore = childNode(withName: "playerScore") as! SKLabelNode
    comScore = childNode(withName: "comScore") as! SKLabelNode

    let bodyBorder = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFrom: self.frame)
    bodyBorder.friction = 0
    bodyBorder.restitution = 1
    self.physicsBody = bodyBorder

    Ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx:20, dy:10))
}

func gameBegin() {
    playerScore.text = String(0)
    comScore.text = String(0)
}

func playerPoint() {
    var comScoreInt: Int = Int(comScore.text!)!
    comScoreInt += 1
    comScore.text = String(comScoreInt)
    Ball.position = (CGPoint(x:0, y:0))
    Ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx:-20,dy:-10))
}

func comPoint() {
    var playerScoreInt: Int = Int(playerScore.text!)!
    playerScoreInt += 1
    playerScore.text = String(playerScoreInt)
    Ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx:20,dy:10))
    Ball.position = (CGPoint(x:0, y:0))

}

func pointCount() {
    computerPaddle.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: Ball.position.y, duration: 0.5))
    if Ball.position.x <= playerPaddle.position.x - 42 {
        playerPoint()
    } else if Ball.position.x >= computerPaddle.position.x + 42 {
        comPoint()
    }

}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        playerPaddle.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: location.y, duration: 0.1))
    }
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)

        playerPaddle.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: location.y, duration: 0))
    }
}


override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
   pointCount()
}
}
```

I'm new to SpriteKit so I don't know how to make this code more efficient. Help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

The speed is very slow, and it can take sevral minuted to recognize point score, and ball position. There is nothing wrong with the playerScore/comScore.text code, it's set to 0 in gamescene.sks

Comment: i think problem is in pointCount function

Comment: Crashes where and with what error? What code did you add that caused the crash? Does it crash every time?

Comment: @JaydeepVyas - I think you're onto something... :-)

Comment: Int(playerScore.text!)!  is the problem

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is `playerScore.text` or `comScore.text` might be `nil` and the app crashes when you try to force unwrap it. In the code you are assigning values to `comScore.text` and `playerScore.text` in `func gameBegin()`. But it is not called anywhere. Try calling that function in may be `didMoveto view` function.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with the casting this line

```
Int(playerScore.text!)! and Int(comScore.text!)!
```

Instead you have to use like this

```
Int(comScore.text?) ?? 0
Int(playerScore.text?) ?? 0
```

Answer (score 0):

About your crash you have forgot to give a value to `playerScore` and `comScore` (you can call your function `gameBegin` inside the `didMove` function) and the compiler probably crash to the line:

```
var comScoreInt: Int = Int(comScore.text!)!
```

because `comScore` text is empty.

I think the function `pointCount()` could be corrected with:

```
func pointCount() {
        if computerPaddle.action(forKey: "moveTo") == nil {
            computerPaddle.run(SKAction.moveTo(y: Ball.position.y, duration: 0.5), withKey:"moveTo")
            if Ball.position.x <= playerPaddle.position.x - 42 {
                playerPoint()
            } else if Ball.position.x >= computerPaddle.position.x + 42 {
                comPoint()
            }
        }
    }
```

This correction limit the execution of this action only when the `computerPaddle` is free of any previous "*moveTo*" executions..

Comment: This code isn't slow and doesn't crash, but, it's not registering a point for me, just bouncing back and forth